# Benchmarking time series forecasting model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, accuracy, moving-average, moving-window

Problem: I'm building a time series forecasting model for daily data wherein, the aim is to forecast for the next one week. So, to validate the model, I'm using a moving window based validation wherein, I take 8 weeks (56 days) of data and forecast for the next one week (7 days) and then I move the window by 7 days till the end of series. With the actual and forecasted values, I'm able to measure the accuracy of forecast.

Ask: Now I want to perform a benchmarking of the model with something very simple like moving average over multiple windows (30, 45, 60) day windows. Is this kind of benchmarking statistically correct ? What is the correct way to benchmark a timeseries forecasting model with something simple like moving average ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing exactly the right thing:

- using a holdout sample (never compare accuracies in-sample!)
- comparing your forecasts to a simple model

Indeed, [it's quite common for a very simple model to outperform more complex ones in forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352), and you should always benchmark against simple methods. [Here are some more suggestions for simple benchmarks.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/3) I'd especially recommend:

- the historical mean value
- the naive no-change forecast (forecast the very last observation out)
- the seasonal naive forecast (to forecast for next Tuesday, use the last Tuesday observation - this models intra-week seasonality in a simple way)

Your moving window approach also makes sense. Keep the length of history in mind - it may be that some methods work better with shorter histories, others with longer ones.