# how to get forecast like zig zag type

Tags: time-series, forecasting

[image]

My model is ARIMA(0,1,1).And diagnostics are ok.but cant get clear values for the forecasting in r.

Comment: You might want to add more information, otherwise the chance for a good answer will remain close to 0. A specific example with code, data and concept would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Your model says that differences in the observations are MA(1):

$$ y_t-y_{t-1}=\theta\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \quad\text{or}\quad y_t=y_{t-1}+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_t.$$

In (point) forecasting, you plug in the mean value for the innovations $\epsilon$, which is zero. So your forecast is just the last observation. (The very first forecast data point could be somewhat off, because that uses the last "observed" innovation, but you may not see it if the MA coefficient is small.)

A "zigzag" pattern can arise in many ways. The simplest would be an AR(1) model with a negative coefficient:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
xx <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(-0.9)),n=100)
model <- arima(xx,order=c(1,0,0))
plot(forecast(model,h=10))
```

[image: zigzag]

However: *why do you **want** a zigzag forecast?* If your data generating process truly is ARIMA(0,1,1), then the flat line will be the best forecast (under squared error loss). Anything else will perform worse. See [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352) Don't be afraid of a flat line forecast!

Comment: Thank you sir.But problem is this is the coconut export prices.then the how can forecast next year.its straight line

Comment: If your data is just noise, then the *data* will be noisy, but the best forecast (i.e., the one that minimizes the expected squared error) will be the *expectation*, i.e., a flat line. Here is an experiment: suppose your past and future data is simply $N(0,1)$ random variables. What is the best forecast for each future time period? You can simulate this and try various approaches.