# Positive forecasts with hts and combinef in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am doing forecasts for a lot of time series. These consist of forecasts for specific items in specific regions, where all regions belong to a country. So this is a hierarchial series.

- Product 1 - Country 1

  1. product 1 - country 1 - region 1-1
  2. product 1 - country 1 - region 1-2
- Product 1 - Country 2

  1. Product 1 - Country 2 - region 2-1
  2. ........
- ........

And then there is of course also the "Total" of all.

My matrix `cmat` contains all bottom level data, i.e. for all products and regions. Every column is a time series. The name of a column is for example: `000214ABCab`. The numbers are the product ID, the next 3 letters are the country, and the next two letters are the region. I want forecasts on this level, but also on the product-country level.

First I was struggling with the performance, as I have a lot of data. In the example below I only use a subset of 1000 time series.

```
subs = cmat[,1:1000]
hh = hts(subs, characters = c(maxlength+3,2))
ally = aggts(hh)

#make list of data tables with time series 
subs2 = as.data.table(t(ally))
subs2$CODE = unlist(hh$labels)
datlist = subs2[, list(list(.SD)),by=CODE]$V1
 setattr(datlist, 'names', subs2$CODE) #code is the identifier of products/country/region

s1 = Sys.time()
fcast = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(subs2)){
    if(i%%1000==0){
        print(i)
    }
    fc = data.table(pmax(forecast(stlf(ts(matrix(datlist[[i]]),frequency=12)),h=12)$mean,0) )
    names(fc) = names(datlist)[i]

    fcast = rbind(fcast, t(fc))
}
s2 = Sys.time()

fcasts = t(fcast)
y.f = combinef(fcasts, get_nodes(hh),keep="all")

s3 = Sys.time()
```

I am also surprised by how fast `combinef` is. However, I only want positive or zero forecasts. Preferably also integer forecasts. I already do `pmax(forecast, 0)` in the loop. But by using `combinef`, I lose this again.

If I do now again `pmax` then I will also lose the functionality of the `combinef`, right? So how can I make the forecasts positive? Also, for me it is not necessary to have a "total forecast" at all, but I don't know if I can omit this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't ensure positivity and sum consistency of hierarchical forecasts if you use `forecast::combinef()`.

What I personally found useful was to set up the summation matrix (see [the original publication by Hyndman et al., 2011](https://robjhyndman.com/publications/hierarchical/)) and then solve the relevant (weighted) least squares problem with additional nonnegativity constraints. This will give you nonnegative and sum consistent forecasts. I have found repeatedly that this approach still results in better forecasts on all levels in the hierarchy.

One possible tool that solves (weighted) least squares with linear constraints is the `pcls()` function in the `mgcv` package. However, this is of course also not optimized to leverage the specific structure of potential forecast hierarchy matrices, so your performance may be significantly worse than if you use `combinef()`.

Comment: Thank you. My data is on spare parts mainly, do you consider `stlf()` as a good method for this?

Comment: Spare parts demand is often [tag:intermittent-time-series], where seasonality is not overly evident. You may want to look at the MAPA algorithm by Kourentzes et al.

Comment: Thank you. I did, but I'm not satisfied with it, see my results in the update on my post. Or do I miss anything when using mapa?

Comment: Your question is now something completely different from the original. This does not fit well with the CV Q&A format - the goal here is not only to discuss and address your current problem, but to build a repository of answers that other people can profit from in the future. If you edit your question after it has been answered and change it heavily, this goal is compromised. Please consider rolling back your edit and if you wish to, asking a new question. (Feel free to link to it in a comment here.) ...

Comment: ... If you do so, please be a little more specific about what you are unsatisfied about with the flat forecast, [which is often quite hard to beat](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352).

Comment: Thank you about that link, and excuse me for wrongly using the post. I deleted the edit and will do some more research about the flat forecast.