# Price Forecasting Problem

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, dropout

I am working on a project for price movement forecasting and I am stuck with poor quality predictions.

At every time-step I am using an LSTM to predict the next 10 time-steps. The input is the sequence of the last 45-60 observations. I tested several different ideas, but they all seems to give similar results. The model is trained to minimize MSE.

For each idea I tried a model predicting 1 step at a time where each prediction is fed back as an input for the next prediction, and a model directly predicting the next 10 steps(multiple outputs). For each idea I also tried using as input just the moving average of the previous prices, and extending the input to input the order book at those time-steps.
Each time-step corresponds to a second.

These are the results so far:

1- The first attempt was using as input the moving average of the last N steps, and predict the moving average of the next 10. 
At time t, I use the ground truth value of the price and use the model to predict t+1....t+10

This is the result

[Predicting moving average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOXxu.png)

On closer inspection we can see what's going wrong:

[Prediction seems to be a flat line. Does not care much about the input data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Xb5.png)

2) The second attempt was trying to predict differences, instead of simply the price movement. The input this time instead of simply being X[t] (where X is my input matrix) would be X[t]-X[t-1].
This did not really help.
The plot this time looks like this:

[Predicting differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toFGz.png)

But on close inspection, when plotting the differences, the predictions are always basically 0.

[Plot of differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSqGU.png)

At this point, I am stuck here and running our of ideas to try. I was hoping someone with more experience in this type of data could point me in the right direction.

Am I using the right objective to train the model? Are there any details when dealing with this type of data that I am missing?
Are there any "tricks" to prevent your model from always predicting similar values to what it last saw? (They do incur in low error, but they become meaningless at that point).

At least just a hint on where to dig for further info would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my config

```
{
    "data": {
        "sequence_length":30,
        "train_test_split": 0.85,
        "normalise": false,
        "num_steps": 5
    },
    "training": {
        "epochs":200,
        "batch_size": 64
    },
    "model": {
        "loss": "mse",
        "optimizer": "adam",
        "layers": [
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 51,
                "input_timesteps": 30,
                "input_dim": 101,
                "return_seq": true,
                "activation": "relu"
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.1
            },
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 51,
                "activation": "relu",
                "return_seq": false
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.1
            },
            {
                "type": "dense",
                "neurons": 101,
                "activation": "relu"
            },
            {
                "type": "dense",
                "neurons": 101,
                "activation": "linear"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice the last layer with 101 neurons. It is not an error. We just want to predict the features as well as the price. In other words, we want to predict the price for time t+1 and use the features predicted to predict the price and new features at time t+2, ...

**Update 2**

```
FEATURES = [

            ## Ask Price ##
            "AskPrice1", "AskPrice2", "AskPrice3", "AskPrice4", "AskPrice5",      

           ## Ask Quantity ##
            "AskQty1", "AskQty2", "AskQty3", "AskQty4", "AskQty5", 

            ## Bid Price ##
            "BidPrice1", "BidPrice2", "BidPrice3", "BidPrice4", "BidPrice5",

           ## Bid Quantity ##
            "BidQty1", "BidQty2", "BidQty3", "BidQty4", "BidQty5",

           ## Cancel Buy Price ##
            #"CancelBuyPrice1", "CancelBuyPrice10", "CancelBuyPrice11", "CancelBuyPrice12",
            #"CancelBuyPrice13", "CancelBuyPrice14", "CancelBuyPrice15", "CancelBuyPrice16", "CancelBuyPrice17",
            #"CancelBuyPrice18", "CancelBuyPrice19", "CancelBuyPrice2", "CancelBuyPrice20", "CancelBuyPrice3", "CancelBuyPrice4",
            #"CancelBuyPrice5", "CancelBuyPrice6", "CancelBuyPrice7", "CancelBuyPrice8", "CancelBuyPrice9", 

           ## Cancel Quantity ##
            "CancelBuyQty1",
            "CancelBuyQty10", "CancelBuyQty11", "CancelBuyQty12", "CancelBuyQty13", "CancelBuyQty14", "CancelBuyQty15",
            "CancelBuyQty16", "CancelBuyQty17", "CancelBuyQty18", "CancelBuyQty19", "CancelBuyQty2", "CancelBuyQty20",   
            "CancelBuyQty3", "CancelBuyQty4", "CancelBuyQty5", "CancelBuyQty6", "CancelBuyQty7", "CancelBuyQty8", "CancelBuyQty9",

            ## Cancel Sell Price ##
            #"CancelSellPrice1", "CancelSellPrice10", "CancelSellPrice11", "CancelSellPrice12", "CancelSellPrice13", 
            #"CancelSellPrice14", "CancelSellPrice15", "CancelSellPrice16", "CancelSellPrice17", "CancelSellPrice18",
            #"CancelSellPrice19", "CancelSellPrice2", "CancelSellPrice20", "CancelSellPrice3", "CancelSellPrice4",
            #"CancelSellPrice5", "CancelSellPrice6", "CancelSellPrice7", "CancelSellPrice8", "CancelSellPrice9",

            ## Cancel Sell Quantity ##
            "CancelSellQty1", "CancelSellQty10", "CancelSellQty11", "CancelSellQty12", "CancelSellQty13", "CancelSellQty14",
            "CancelSellQty15", "CancelSellQty16", "CancelSellQty17", "CancelSellQty18", "CancelSellQty19", "CancelSellQty2",
            "CancelSellQty20", "CancelSellQty3", "CancelSellQty4", "CancelSellQty5", "CancelSellQty6", "CancelSellQty7",
            "CancelSellQty8", "CancelSellQty9", 

            ## Limit Buy Price ##
            #"LimitBuyPrice1", "LimitBuyPrice10", "LimitBuyPrice11", "LimitBuyPrice12",   
            #"LimitBuyPrice13", "LimitBuyPrice14", "LimitBuyPrice15", "LimitBuyPrice16", "LimitBuyPrice17", "LimitBuyPrice18",
            #"LimitBuyPrice19", "LimitBuyPrice2", "LimitBuyPrice20", "LimitBuyPrice3", "LimitBuyPrice4", "LimitBuyPrice5",    
            #"LimitBuyPrice6", "LimitBuyPrice7", "LimitBuyPrice8", "LimitBuyPrice9", 

            ## Limit Buy Quantity ##
            "LimitBuyQty1", "LimitBuyQty10",
            "LimitBuyQty17", "LimitBuyQty18", "LimitBuyQty19", "LimitBuyQty2", "LimitBuyQty20", "LimitBuyQty3", "LimitBuyQty4",
            "LimitBuyQty11", "LimitBuyQty12", "LimitBuyQty13", "LimitBuyQty14", "LimitBuyQty15", "LimitBuyQty16",
            "LimitBuyQty5", "LimitBuyQty6", "LimitBuyQty7", "LimitBuyQty8", "LimitBuyQty9", 

            ## Limit Sell Price ##
            #"LimitSellPrice1",   
            #"LimitSellPrice10", "LimitSellPrice11", "LimitSellPrice12", "LimitSellPrice13", "LimitSellPrice14",
            #"LimitSellPrice15", "LimitSellPrice16", "LimitSellPrice17", "LimitSellPrice18", "LimitSellPrice19",
            #"LimitSellPrice2", "LimitSellPrice20", "LimitSellPrice3", "LimitSellPrice4", "LimitSellPrice5", 
            #"LimitSellPrice6", "LimitSellPrice7", "LimitSellPrice8", "LimitSellPrice9", 

            ## Limit Sell Quantity ##
            "LimitSellQty1", "LimitSellQty10",
            "LimitSellQty11", "LimitSellQty12", "LimitSellQty13", "LimitSellQty14", "LimitSellQty15", "LimitSellQty16",
            "LimitSellQty17", "LimitSellQty18", "LimitSellQty19", "LimitSellQty2", "LimitSellQty20", "LimitSellQty3",     
            "LimitSellQty4", "LimitSellQty5", "LimitSellQty6", "LimitSellQty7", "LimitSellQty8", "LimitSellQty9",

            ## Others ##
            "midprice"]
            #"MarketBuyQty", "MarketSellQty", "VWAP-midprice", "midprice"]
            # "BestAsk", "BestAskDiff", "BestBid", "BestBidDiff"]
```

Comment: I just want to add to Stephan Kolassa great answer.  As mentioned, EMH implies that stock prices follow random walks.  Random walks have no tendency to revert to their mean.  For this reason, prediction intervals for such series  increase with each step.  As a result, multi-step forecast of random walks are exceptionally bad. In contrast prediction intervals for series which don't follow random walks eventually stabilize (i.e. the series will eventually revert to its mean).

Comment: The markets are probably efficient, but in my experience LSTMs are just not that useful in time series analysis - see this gist: https://gist.github.com/HristoBuyukliev/678152c504f5e917887c2fb1ea52778e . They can't seem to even model exponential moving average. In this gist I used one hidden unit, but even with like 20 units, they failed miserably. VAR-like models are not much better. I think manual feature construction is unavoidable at the moment. Once you've added manual features, you might as well reformulate the problem as tabular data and plug xgboost or whatever in.

Comment: I would strongly urge you to start with something relatively well-studied (e.g. an ARIMA model with some exogenous variable) and built up. I have seen case studies where people using LSTM and GRU outperformed ARIMA/ES methodologies but it took significant expertise both in time-series forecasting as well as NN. Focusing on getting the basic of forecasting principles right first and then move into exotic methods extending them. The reverse is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are providing support for the [efficient market hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient-market_hypothesis):

> The efficient-market hypothesis (EMH) is a theory in financial economics that states that asset prices fully reflect all available information. A direct implication is that it is impossible to "beat the market" consistently on a risk-adjusted basis since market prices should only react to new information.

Essentially, this means that the optimal forecast for future prices is the current price, which already carries all the information there is. Equivalently, the optimal forecast for price *movements* (i.e., differences in consecutive prices) is zero. Burton Malkiel's *A Random Walk Down Wall Street* is a nice nontechnical introduction.

There may simply not be much information in your data, even if the strong EMH may be false. You may need to leverage external information.

Also relevant: [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352) and [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNznD9hMEh0&t=18s - Take a look on that video. That guy is one of the most profitable hedge fund manager. He doesn't beleive in EMH.

Comment: @user1050421: Whether, EMH holds or not, is not the same as saying that findings "provide support" for it. Of course EMH, especially in very short time-scales where [market clearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_clearing) cannot occur, does not always hold; that does not mean though that our data might not exhibit behaviour that potentially supports it.