# Auto-Arima creates a straight line help

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, prediction

I'm trying to create a forecast using autoarima with some data, but i always get a straight-line, can someone please help me? :)
This is what i've got so far

```
install.packages("forecast")
install.packages("scales")
library(forecast)
datos <-read.csv("C:/Users/sarit/Documents/SÉPTIMO CUATRI/iieg/dator.csv",header=T)
monto=datos$monto.XVI
montots<-ts(monto)
montots<-ts(monto,frequency = 12,start = c(2007,1), end = c(2018,8))
montots
plot(montots)
auto.arima(montots) 
fit=arima(montots,order=c(0,1,0))
a=forecast(fit,h=5)
plot(forecast(fit,h=5))
```

So basically, with the autoarima function i get (0,1,0), and when i plot the forecast i get a straight line like this:
[image]

my data looks like this[image]

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note first of all that your plot does not come from a call to `auto.arima()`, but from one to `arima()`. There is a difference.

By supplying `order=c(0,1,0)` to `arima()`, you tell it to fit a model of the following type:

$$ y_t-y_{t-1} = \epsilon_t, $$

or

$$ y_t=y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t. $$

That is, you believe that the *increments* over the last observation follow a normal distribution, $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

For your point forecast, `forecast()` will use the expected value for $\epsilon_t$. Which is zero. So your next forecast is simply the last observation:

$$ \hat{y}_t=y_{t-1}. $$

And this is iterated. You end up with a flat line.

Try actually fitting using `auto.arima()`. However, your time series does not exhibit any obvious structure, like trend or seasonality. (Autoregressive or moving average behavior are harder to spot by eye.) In such a situation, a flat line may well be the best forecast: [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352)

You may be interested in the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).

Comment: Thank you!!  I was wondering, would you use another type of function for this kind of data? Because I tried using the auto.arima fitting but still doesn't work