# machine learning algorithms (Xgb, LSTM, others) for time series forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have seen many kernels that are using machine learning algorithms  (Xgb, LSTM, others) on time series forecasting.

A time series data typically has trend and seasonal components. 
In general my question is

1. Is it necessary to remove trend and seasonality (i.e make it stationary ) before applying  machine learning/supervised learning (Xgb, LSTM, others) algorithms for time series data ?
2. when will machine learning/supervised learning (Xgb, LSTM, others) algorithms for time series data gives good result? When will they not give good result?
3. Any guidelines for using machine learning/supervised learning algorithms for time series data ?
4. If there is seasonality and trend how to tackle the problem?
   One way is to detrend and remove seasonality, and then use ML algorithm for forecasting.
   Are there any other approaches especially if time series has trend?
5. Finally, How will you verify the forecast results? I mean, can we look at the residuals/something to infer forecast results makes sense.

Comment: Your should definitly check http://freerangestats.info/blog/2016/11/06/forecastxgb

Comment: As some more information in machine learning approaches vs. traditional statistical ones, the very recent M4 competition just closed this year and I highly encourage you to take a read on the results: researchgate.net/publication/… In summary, all "pure" ML approaches did not perform well at all. Out of the top five models, I believe four were ensembles of classical methods, and first place was a hybrid neural network + Holt-Winters multiplicative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. "ML" approaches will typically do better in high signal to noise situations, and with enough data. With less data, the traditional forecasting approaches are often superior.
2. This is a very broad question. One recommendation: familiarize yourself with the state of the art in "classical" forecasting. I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/). Test your ML forecasts against simple benchmarks, [which surprisingly often outperform more complex algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352).
3. One way to deal with trend is to include a linearly increasing predictor and extrapolate that out. Forecasters often find that dampening the trend improves forecasts. Similarly, you can include periodic functions like harmonics or bump functions as predictors to model seasonality.
4. There are many [accepted measures of forecast accuracy](https://otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html). You may also want to look through the tag wikis on the [MAPE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mape/info), the [MASE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mase/info), the [MAE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mae/info) or the [MSE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mse/info), or through [threads tagged both "forecasting" and "accuracy"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting%2baccuracy).

Comment: Can you explain 3?

Comment: For trend, include a predictor that counts the seconds, days or whatever time granularity you have, starting at an arbitrary beginning of time. Both historically and for the future. For seasonality, transform this into multiple periodic functions whose periodicity is a multiple of your seasonality base periodicity. E.g., for intra-yearly seasonality on daily data, include one sine wave with period 365.25, one with 182.6, one with 121.8 etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply.   According to the the above comment,  it is not always mandatory to make your time series stationary before applying ml algorithm to time series forecasting.    Am I right?

Comment: @aranglol: thank you. I am aware of the M4 competition. (Right now, I happen to be working on a commentary that the guest editor of the IJF invited me to write.) Your summary is correct, but the question really is how informative the M4 setup was. ML approaches work better with (lots of) causal and meta data, and this was not available in the M4. I have heard that some ML experts declined to participate for this exact reason. I am by no means a proponent of ML, but the M4 provides only a very weak argument against it.

Comment: Stationarity is a tricky thing. "Plain vanilla" ML implementations, e.g., LSTMs, that assume stationarity will of course require stationarity. But it's straightforward to model certain kinds of nonstationarity without transforming the input. For instance, you can model trends and seasonalities - two kinds of nonstationarity - in the way I described. So the question is really what assumptions your algorithm of choice makes.

Comment: @StephanKolossa Sorry, I meant the response to be towards the topic creator and not to you. I'll delete my comment. As an aside, that is very interesting to hear your insight on this. When you say metadata, are you referring to large amounts of potential features/predictors to forecast time series then?

Comment: @aranglol: by metadata, I mean all kinds of "additional" data. E.g., time series characteristics or attributes that may or may not be time-varying. For product sales forecasting, that could include things like product category information. These can be used for implicit clustering

Comment: @StephanKolassa
just to confirm - Based on your comments above, does LSTM require stationary data ? Can we handle non stationary data ( data with strong seasonality based on few predictors) with out making the series stationary in LSTMs by using periodic predictors? 
 If you can, can you please answer this, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494149/handling-time-series-data-with-seasonality-and-trend-for-training-lstms

Comment: @tjt: sorry, I don't know enough about LSTMs to answer that with any confidence...