# Should I remove the trend from timeseries when using DeepAR

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, trend, recurrent-neural-network

I saw that for some other algorithms for timeseries data it is advised to remove trend and seasonality before doing the prediction (ex: [ARIMA and LSTM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385988/machine-learning-algorithms-xgb-lstm-others-for-time-series-forecasting))

I figured out from the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04110.pdf) that SageMaker's DeepAR deals internally with seasonality, but does the same thing stands for trend?
Let's say I have multiple timeseries, where some of them have positive, and some have negative trend. Should I remove trend and then use DeepAR prediction, or should I just ignore it and let DeepAR handle it?