# Handling time series data with seasonality and trend for training LSTMs

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm

Do I need to remove seasonality and trend from time series data, before using it for training lstm. Or, with sufficient data, can LSTMs recognize the pattern in trend and seasonality ?  I have 3 years of data for 40 different time series (say task is to predict weekly sales for 40 products) and the time series has yearly seasonality would this be sufficient (I have about 10 independent features to predict sales) .

yearly seasonality of series - the sales rapidly spike and peak during summer and then gradually follow a down trend and suddenly see a spike and peak again during summer. Can I model this with stateless lstm ( using different lags (51 week, 52 week, 53 week etc. ) of the sales and lag of other features) or should I use only stateful ?

I have only about 40 time series with 150 data points each and concerned that data might be insufficient for stateful

Comment: this is very interesting. Why do you want to go with LSTM's? did you try other methods such as gradient boosted trees?

Comment: Tried xgb on this. But also want to explore lstms. Because lstms are suitedfor sequential time series data and can identify patterns in them