# sklearn Support Vector Regression - test data prediction is constant

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, svm

I am just getting into learning some basic machine learning for a project at university and I am having a little trouble with SVR on sklearn.

When training a model I can change the epsilon value and see the prediction changing from almost perfect replication to good estimates. However nothing I seem to do changes the output predictions on the testing data, the values are constant. I have a feeling it could be due to data formatting because at one point I changed the index column to be the first column on my csv and the first testing output changed however after that they became constant again.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

KPN = pd.read_csv('Regression.csv').astype('float32')

def Split_Train_Test(data, test_ratio):
    train_set_size = 1 - int(len(data) * test_ratio)
    train_set = data[:train_set_size]
    test_set = data[train_set_size:]
    return train_set, test_set

train, test = Split_Train_Test(KPN, 0.1)
```

The data has 1200 rows so I am just going to use the first 100 for an example:

```
X = train.iloc[:50,0:1]
y = train["output"][0:50]
X_test = train.iloc[50:100,0:1]


from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.05)
svr_rbf.fit(X,y)

svr_rbf.predict(X)
array([2.72315689, 2.65343986, 2.61527852, 2.63005085,...,2.53509259])

svr_rbf.predict(X_test)
array([2.5851449, 2.6134029 , 2.6134029, 2.6134029,..., 2.6134029])
```

The X values are just time points, so 1,2,3,.... and the Y values are just points of a time series.

edit:
Added time plots
[image: Time Series on training data]
[image: Time Series on testing data]

Comment: what does the timeseries look like if you plot it?

Comment: @Sycorax I have added the time plots for you. The input X has other features (which also affect movements) not included in the code above, just thought it would be worth saying that even with other features included I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is observed is a direct consequence of using a potentially improper parameter set for `svr`. It appears that especially the `epsilon` used, i.e. the minimum distance between actual and predicted values that needs to be observed so a penalty is induced during fitting, is somewhat large; therefore errors are not adequately penalised and this leads to potential under-fitting. In addition as there is an obvious sequential nature to our data, the influence of the parameter `gamma`, i.e. how far the influence of a single training example reaches, is going to be important too.

I quickly eye-balled the data from the graph shown and made some quick predictions to show how strong the effect of `epsilon` can be in this case.

Some final application-specific comments:

1. The flat estimate is not necessarily bad! Off the bat I would say it is actually "correct"; following Makrydakis et al. (2018) [Statistical and Machine Learning forecasting methods: Concerns and ways forward](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889) setting `epsilon` "*equal to the noise level of the training sample*" is a perfectly reasonable thing to start with. "*Beating the historical mean*" as a forecast (as the current flat-line suggests), is not as trivial as it sounds (see the excellent CV thread on : [Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124955/is-it-unusual-for-the-mean-to-outperform-arima)  for more details).
2. Time-series forecasting tasks tend to be dominated by exponential smoothing and/or ARIMA models; SVMs, while promising, never really established themselves as a strong alternative. I would suggest you consider such approaches if you have not done already.
3. Consider using rolling time-window approach when cross-validating the fitting procedure for a time-series model. Rob Hyndman has written extensively on [time-series cross-validation](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/), his book with Athanasopoulos has a very nice section about this available [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html). In Python check [`TimeSeriesSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) from `sklearn.model_selection`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVR

dtrain=np.random.uniform(0,0.00100,[100,2])      
dtrain[:50,1] = np.array([2.770, 2.690, 2.560, 2.630, 2.730, 2.720, 2.690, 2.680, 2.600, 2.630, 
                          2.580, 2.615, 2.72,  2.670, 2.690, 2.710, 2.705, 2.660, 2.610, 2.580, 
                          2.650, 2.600, 2.550, 2.600, 2.630, 2.61,  2.620, 2.660, 2.670, 2.665, 
                          2.595, 2.625, 2.685, 2.680, 2.650, 2.660, 2.550, 2.540, 2.520, 2.486, 
                          2.551, 2.551, 2.580, 2.605, 2.525, 2.510, 2.510, 2.480, 2.515, 2.485])
dtrain[:,0] = np.arange(1,101)

X = dtrain[:50,0]
y = dtrain[:50,1]
X_test = dtrain[50:99,0]

svr_rbf_original = SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.05) 
svr_rbf_original.fit(X.reshape(-1,1),y)
svr_rbf_twicked = SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.003, gamma=0.001)
svr_rbf_twicked.fit(X.reshape(-1,1),y)

plt.plot(X, y,linestyle="",marker="o", label='Raw')  
plt.plot(X, svr_rbf_original.predict(X.reshape(-1,1)), label='Within sample fit')
plt.plot(X_test, svr_rbf_original.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1)), label='Fit eps:0.05')
plt.plot(X_test, svr_rbf_twicked.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1)), label='Fit eps:0.003 / gamma:0.001') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is a brilliant answer and will help me greatly. I understand SVR may not be the best approach here, I am currently doing a research project at university on comparing traditional methods and new machine learning methods to predict time series. I also want to note I did a bit more data preprocessing, I am still new to this and so am just experimenting to help my learning, I had not scaled my data properly and after doing so I managed to see improvements. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool! I am happy I could help!