# Tentative ARIMA models for forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am doing out-of-sample forecasting with ARIMA and derived one model (0,0,1) with auto.arima on a differenced time series. The series is daily observations over the course of 3 years. I would like to derive one more model (it has to be ARIMA) to forecast with to be able to compare the accuracy.  I have tried to find alternative models with loops that finds the lowest AIC and BIC with the result of an (0,0,1). Also when plotting the residual there is a small significant correlation at lag 15, but adding that lag will not make a good alternative model.

1.What other ways are there to find tentative forecasting models? It needs a theoretical ground and I am not utilizing machine learning.

2.And when reporting the final model is it praxis to report a differenced model (ex ARIMA (0,0,1) y' = ...., or should one report that it is a ARIMA(0,1,1) with y = ...?

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at [the difficulties you seem to have with your ARIMA(0,0,1) model (or is it ARIMA(0,1,1), since you mention differencing?)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/439536/1352). I'd strongly suggest you compare your model to some very simple alternatives, [which surprisingly often are quite competitive with ARIMA and other more complex methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352).

For instance, an overall mean is an ARIMA(0,0,0) with nonconstant mean, and a naive random-walk forecast is ARIMA(1,0,0) with AR(1) coefficient $\phi_1=1$, so both are ARIMA models as you require.

Comment: ok so then try to model with arima(0,0,0) and arima(1,0,0)? When I tried with arima(1,0,0) though , the AR coefficient was not significant.

Comment: That would argue for ARIMA(0,0,0) with a nonconstant mean. Take a look at forecast accuracy out-of-sample.

Comment: Thanks! Also would it be possible for you to look at the second question I just added?