# Extract best p,d,q value from AUTO ARIMA which has high variance in forecast

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I am trying AUTO ARIMA model on a dataset which has no trend and no seasonality. When I run it, it will forecast a flat line from p,d,q value selected from AIC. But when I take another approach, where I iterate for a range of p,d,q and pass it to ARIMA, it shows better result with variation in forecast. It may have high AIC, but it was  clearly a better forecast. I cant do this manual ARIMA because I have to forecast 1000+ timeseries (small datasets with 100 data point). Is there any way we can extract p,d,q in AUTO ARIMA based on high variance in forecast result?

Ex:

Below Image is result of AUTO ARIMA. Green line is forecast

[image]

Below image is result of Manual ARIMA. Orange line is forecast (here test data is not shown)

[image]

Comment: No. It sounds like your goal is to overfit as much as possible rather than produce good forecasts, so just set $p$, $d$ and $q$ to arbitrarily high values and it should work pretty well.

Comment: i want good forecast. But i want to show some variation in forecast instead of a flat line. When u say high value, u suggest pdq>3,4,5?

Comment: Why do you think a variable forecast is better than a flat one? [Very often, a flat line is the best forecast possible.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352)

Comment: This question could benefit from more detail about how you evaluate a forecast to be "good" (it doesn't appear to be the same definition that most people use). For example, if you could include data and the result of `forecast::auto.arima` as well as what you consider a "better" forecast for the same series.

Comment: I have updated the question Chris