# How to chain separate models into a single unified model (where predictions of one sub-model form an input to another)?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, bayesian-network

Our team is tasked with forecasting several timeseries at the daily (or hourly) level:

1. number of calls ('demand')
2. number of calls catergorised as important
3. mean vehical travel time to caller
4. mean time to answer call

These variables all form part of an *integrated* system that we want to model/understand.

Currently, we are using R to fit 4 *separate* general additive models (GAMs) to do this. Each model makes its forecast based on a few relavant time series. **Some of the forecasts of those models are used as inputs to the other models**: models 2 and 3 both use the forecasts of model 1; model 4 uses the forecasts of models 2 and 3... So if model 1 is poor, this will influence the other models (and if model 2 or 3 are poor, so will be model 4).

I would like to explore methods (not necassarily GAMs) that can reflect the intergrated nature of the system.

Specifically, I want to model these 4 timeseries simultaneously, while allowing some of the predicted timeseries to be used to forecast the others, in a unified way. In other words, can I create a network of models where the outputs of some form the inputs of others? In yet other words, is there a way to link submodels together into a single larger model?

So far, my searches have led me to think about using continuous time structural equation modelling (using the R package 'ctsem'), but I'm unsure if this is appropriate for timeseries with hundreds/thousands of points? Another approach could be dynamic bayesian networks?

It feels like this sort of thing must exist and I'm trying to find the right search terms to start me off. Any tips/direction on how to forecast multiple timeseries that depend on each other (as well as on other predictors) would be much appreciated!

Comment: What about using a [Kalman filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)? Knowing what the data looks like would also allow us to give better advice.

Comment: [It is often surprisingly hard to beat rather simple benchmarks in forecasting.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/124955/1352) So I would very much recommend you also implement something like `forecast::ets()` with the presumable weekly seasonality, and `forecast::tbats()` to account for the [tag:multiple-seasonalities] likely present in your data. Yes, that does not answer your question. But these methods may be surprisingly competitive, and can be implemented at a fraction of the time of more complex methods.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I appreciate your point (and have indeed found that it's very hard to improve over very simple models. One of my motivations for having a single estimated model instead of a lot of separate, but inter-dependent, is purely practical - currently it's painful to run different scenarios about the link between a variable we input to model 1 and the output of model 4 (our users often ask us for such info). With one model, we would eliminate a lot of fiddly work in this regard, and the whole system might be easier for our users to interpret.