# Using SVM to predict wind speed--how do I calculate the accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, svm

This is my first foray into machine learning, as I usually rely on statistical methods.

In the past I've used SVM and its worked, but this is usually with data that is classification (e.g. iris and spam data). Currently, I am trying to using SVM to predict hourly wind speed data. Recorded wind speed can run anywhere from 0 to 45 in this data set, so essentially 45 categories.

Below is my code, which all works completely fine. The data set I'm using is an xts object which runs from 2016/01/01 to 2017/04/31 (20,423 observations). Aside from wind speed, the data set also contains 15 predictor variables which I include in the model.

```
svmtrain <- window(wdsp.ts.sub, 
                   end = as.POSIXct("2016-03-31 23:00:00"))
svmtest <- window(wdsp.ts.sub,
                  start = as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 00:00:00"))

# run kernel SVM

fitsvm <- ksvm(wdsp ~ .,
               data = svmtrain)

predsvm <- predict(fitsvm, svmtest[,2:16])

svmtab <- table(svmtest$wdsp, predsvm)
```

The last line of code is how I would normally compute my accuracy table, but it doesn't really make sense in this case.

How can I compute how accurate this model is, especially in comparison with something more intuitive/easy to understand like an ARIMA?

Answer (score 1):

You have a time series, as you also indicate by contrasting your SVM to ARIMA. There are a number of common accuracy measures for time series forecasts, including the [rmse](/questions/tagged/rmse) or the [mae](/questions/tagged/mae).

In your case, I would go with the (R)MSE, since wind speeds are presumably asymmetrically distributed, and [minimizing the MAE leads to forecasting the conditional *median*, not the mean, so your forecasts will be biased](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355538/1352).

[Here is the section on "Evaluating forecast accuracy"](https://otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html) from the excellent free online textbook [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your reply. In terms of which measures for accuracy, that's fine, and you can extract those from R using accuracy() from Hyndman's forecast package. However, your response has made me realise what I need to do, which is to simply convert the svm forecasts to a ts object, and then use accuracy. Thanks!