# Low MSE between the vectors but different distribution

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, artificial-intelligence

I have two output tensors whose MSE is really small (0.04) but on checking the distribution of the tensors they are very different.

[image: Distribution of input tensor]

[image: Distribution of output tensor]

I am using:

> torch.nn.MSE(output_tensor, input_tensor) = 0.04

I am just wondering how can this happen?

Edit 1: Here the tensors are the learned representations of words in sentences. So their shape is [batch_size x num_tokens x embed_dimension], for my case [batch_size x 16 x 512]. I wanted to check if two tensors are similar.

Comment: Keep in mind that the RMSE is $0.2$, which is about a fifth of the range of your observations. That does not sound especially small. $//$ [Histograms are not the most useful plots to make for this assessment.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/630772/247274)

Comment: @Dave, the RMSE is 4% which is pretty good on the numbers but the actual results are very worst. Thus I checked the distribution which looks like above.

I am just wondering if I have wrongly used MSE loss or it is actual problem of the model. But as the MSE is very low, the model is not updated and produces same tensor everytime.

Comment: I agree with @Dave . The histogram is not the right tool for the comparison, as explained in the linked post. Also, your MSE, not your RMSE, is 4%.