# How to fit a dataset like this, and what's the recommended evaluate metrics for it

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model-selection

the dataset seems like non-linear,
is there any recommended way to fit the datatset? since it's a non-linear regression problem, what's the correct way to evaluate the model's prediction? is the MSE score useful for this problems?
[image]

Comment: For evaluating predictions, [this thread may be helpful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/638194/1352).

Comment: Hi Stephan, you mention "If you want to predict the conditional expectation, use the MSE."  Can I interpret it this way, if you want to predict what's the mean value of the target when inv = 2 , use MSE

Comment: Yes, exactly. The paper I referenced in that answer may be helpful; feel free to reach out to me on ResearchGate for it if you are interested.

Comment: thanks Stephan. one more question, as you can see, the target in this example is norm distributed and the mean is around 0, does the MSE still a good evaluator ?  Intuitively, if we just use 0 as prediction, we will got the minimal MSE value.