# Books or articles to study different forecasting techniques for lumpy and intermittent demand

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references, intermittent-time-series

I am doing a project to forecast demand for an automotive firm making spare parts. Using average demand interval (ADI) and square of the Coefficient of Variation (CV2), I have categorized product SKUs into smooth, erratic, lumpy and intermittent. There are ARIMA, exponential smoothing techniques for smooth demand. However, I am unable to find enough literature for lumpy and intermittent demand. There are 3 methods that have been mentioned in several blogs for intermittent -

1) Croston's method
2) Adjusted Croston's method
3) Bootstrap method

I am reading about these 3 methods. However, I haven't found any literature on lumpy demand forecasting.

Can some please suggest me some good books or articles to understand the different forecasting techniques for lumpy and intermittent demand (can have state space and neural networks also)? If that book or article explains the above 3 methods, it will be an added bonus for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have already gone through these articles -
1) https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/croston-forecast-model-for-intermittent-demand-360287a17f5f
2) http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/06/11/on-intermittent-demand-model-optimisation-and-selection/
3) https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Kourentzes-2014-Intermittent-Optimisation.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/idcat.pdf) by Hyndman and Kostenko proposes the following schema for applying models based on the $ADI$ and $CV2$ coefficients that you have mentioned. Notice that **CRO** stands for the simple Croston Method and **SBA** for the bias adjusted version of the Croston Method.

[image]

For count data model there are three main approaches that you could consider:

- Ad-hoc models. Croston model and the modified versions.
- Statistical based models. Like an INARMA or GARMA models.
- Regression models. Zero Inflated, Hurdle or Poisson-Tweedie Regression

**Ad-hoc models** can account for reducing the bias (error in the prediction) in the forecast like the SBA, but if you update the forecast only in periods of positive demand it has a negative effect for periods of highly intermittent demand, in this case the TSB model is more suitable. The **INARMA model** is more adecuate if you would like to consider also the lead time for inventory replenishment. Now, **Zero Inflated or Hurdle Regression** is more useful when you have a great amount of zeros in your data. However, the **Poisson-Tweedie regression** can account for zeros present, extreme values and over dispersion (the variance is greater than the expected).

To get an insight **about the theory of this models**, I suggest you to consider

- Regression Analysis of Count Data by Colin Cameron and Pravin Trivedi.
- Managing Intermittent Demand by Torben Engelmeyer.

Regarding **practical implementations in R**

- Regression Models. This [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf) explains how to implement them. It considers from the Poisson to the Hurdle model, also you could consider the [ZIM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZIM/index.html) package for Zero Inflated Models. Also [tweeDESeq](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tweeDEseq/versions/1.18.0) can be considered as an alternative for the Tweedie models.
- Ad-hoc models. [tsintermittent](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsintermittent/tsintermittent.pdf) implements the Croston, [SBA](https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/06/23/intermittent-demand-forecasting-package-for-r/) and TSB model.

It is important also to consider an appropiate metric for evaluating the forecast, because traditional metrics like $RMSE$ or $MAE$ tend to bias forecast in favour of zero demand forecast. [Hyndman and Koehler](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/mase.pdf) suggest to consider the [MASE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124365/interpretation-of-mean-absolute-scaled-error-mase) as metric.

Also, the current M5 forecasting competition in Kaggle considers sku's with lot of zeros, here is a link for an [example](https://www.kaggle.com/kyakovlev/m5-three-shades-of-dark-darker-magic) of a Tree Based Model that considers [Tweedie Regression](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html). Finally, I have provided a brief explanation of count models on this [repo](https://github.com/TremaMiguel/Forecasting), I would really appreciate your comments.

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation :). It's a great starting point for anyone. I would also like to add few more links and articles that I found helpful-
1) Blogs by Nikolaos Kourentzes - 
      a) https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/?s=intermittent
      b) **Forecasting using neural network** - https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/paper_Intermittent_NN_Kourentzes.pdf
      c) **Forecasting using Ad-hoc models and discussion on different error methods** - https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Kourentzes-2014-Intermittent-Optimisation.pdf

Comment: Other resources - 
1) **General methods for intermittent forecasting** - https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/pg/waller/pdfs/Intermittent_Demand_Forecasting.pdf

2) **Intuitive and simple explanation on medium**:  https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/croston-forecast-model-for-intermittent-demand-360287a17f5f